# angular ui-router child states dynamic

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I explain my situation to you: I have an angular app that uses UIRouter. There are various states (homepage, about, discover, contact etcetc). I need to create an 'About' page that has 3 child-states' about1 ',' about2 ', about3'. The states are managed by a PageComponent which, depending on the state you want to view, renders a series of partial-components associated with the state.
What I want to do is go to the 'about' status, get a dynamic link list of his children and click on one of these links to view the content of the children. The children can be 3 or more and their structure is not the same but different between them.
What I want to do, I think, is similar to the example on ui-router guide (for the 'people' state), but I don't really understand how to set it all up.
ui-router-example: https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/tutorial/hellogalaxy

```
{
 name: 'app.about',
 url: '/about',
 params: {
     slug: {
     value: 'about',
     raw: true,
     }
 },
 component: PageComponent,
},
{
  name: 'app.about.child',
  url: '/:childSlug',
  component: ChildComponent
},
```